# Now that Facebook Offline Access is deprecated, is there any way to access user data after 2 hours?

Tags: facebook

There are some types of Facebook apps where important features depend on the offline access that is now deprecated, and it wouldn't be practical to make the user visit your app every day to refresh credentials.

It seems that it's possible to extend an access token to last for 60 days instead of two hours, and that's a lot more reasonable. But the documentation is currently vague about how to design for this workflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook 60 day access token and Deprecated Offline\_Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329564/facebook-60-day-access-token-and-deprecated-offline-access)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a clear resource on the workflow for getting a 60 day token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation