# Starting May 1st. Will all access tokens issued by Facebook expire in 60 days?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Will all access tokens automatically be issued for 60 days, or will I need to continue to use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

To exchange my short-term access token for 60 days version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question a couple of weeks ago:

[Facebook 60 day access token and Deprecated Offline_Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329564/facebook-60-day-access-token-and-deprecated-offline-access)

It was answered by a Facebook Support Engineer who stated that enabling the "deprecate offline access" feature will give you 60 day tokens (no exchange required).  On May 1st this feature will be switched on across the board and all tokens will be 60 days.

Comment: I've read your question before posting mine. However, I don't the Facebook guy telling that it will become the default Facebook platform behavior to issue 60 days access token. All it says is that "deprecate offline access" will be enabled. Which simply means that you are able to exchange your access token for a 60 days access token. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Switch on "Deprecate offline access" now and request a fresh token.  You'll see that after enabling this feature the token has an expires time of 60 days (~5 184 000 Seconds).  If this feature is going to be switched on across the board on May 1st then all tokens will be 60 days.