# Deprecated offline access in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just created last week an App and I've read that offline access doesn't work with newly created apps.(I haven't found any tutorial on the web. I am really new to facebook apps)
with this new change in facebook, I don't know how to use the current thing.

I badly need this feature because I don't want the user keeps logging-in in facebook everytime he visits and posts a status in my site as well in his facebook wall. I just want the user to be stayed connected and be able to post on his wall automatically thru my site once he authorized my app.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook 60 day access token and Deprecated Offline\_Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329564/facebook-60-day-access-token-and-deprecated-offline-access)

Answer (score 2):

There are very clear and simple instructions on the following documentation to explain what you need to do to switch to long-life access tokens:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Also, from your description, it sounds like you are spamming and breaking Facebook Platform Policies. Users will hate any app that automatically posts on their behalf, so I recommend you do not do that, as either people will stop using your app or they'll report it and it'll get banned.