# Can't get long lived tokens working properly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I removed the offline_access permissions, revoked the offline_access permissions, and set my app as native. Now instead of getting the 2 hs token, I get a 24 hs token, but is supposed to give a 60 day token, someone knows what's happening here?

Already tried:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$APP_ID&client_secret=$APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=$TOKEN

And still getting 24 hs token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the applications created before the new policy will use long lived tokens until the definitive rollout, any new application created after they announced the new token policy will expire in the expected time

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook 60 day access token and Deprecated Offline_Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329564/facebook-60-day-access-token-and-deprecated-offline-access)

According to this post, the (deprecate) offline access setting has to be on.

Comment: Thanks, albeit that option is set correctly the tokens lasts 24 hs